# Umbraco: Get value from a content child property

Tags: umbraco, blogs, dropdown

I'm creating a blog with the CMS Umbraco. To create a post i've in Umbraco's Content a **Home** where you have a **Post** as a child item.

When you create this Post you have a dropdown-picker for categories, I want to get the values from this categories dropdown-picker to my sidebar to display all categories avaliable on the blog.

I want my dropdownpickers-value on my sidebar. What's the easiest approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[UmbracoHelper - GetPreValues](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/#getprevalueasstring-int-prevalueid)

Regards

Craig

Answer (score 0):

GetPreValues was the answer, Thanks. This worked out for me.

```
  @foreach (var categoryPrevalue in ApplicationContext.Services.DataTypeService.GetPreValuesByDataTypeId(YourDatatypeID).ToList())
                {
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>@categoryPrevalue</span>
                    </a>
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to handle categories, but one of the best ways I have found is to create a Common Area from Root with a categories child within. Within categories you add all the category children.

- Common Area - Categories - Category

Instead of creating the categories as prevalue dropdown they are exposed as objects that are easily editted.

To show these categories on your template use a bit of Umbraco Helper Magic.

```
@{
    var blogCategories = Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath("//categories");
}
```

This will yeald an IPublishedContent object that you can iterate over to get the category name

```
foreach(var item in blogCategories.Where("Visible")
{
    <li>@item.Name</li>
}
```